# "Could not find generator gmaps4rails:install in rails 4"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i am using gmaps4rails gem for showing maps on the template but when i am installing the gem 
is showing

gem 'gmaps4rails'
bundle install
rails generate gmaps4rails:install

"Could not find generator gmaps4rails:install."

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

initially I used these gems and got error of Could not find generator `gmaps4rails:install`

```
ruby 2.0.0
rails 3.2.13
gmaps4rails-2.1.1
```

then  replaced gmaps4rails with older version

```
gmaps4rails -1.5.6
```

Working fine now..

Answer (score 1):

In gmaps4rails 2.0, You don't need to go with rails g gmaps4rails:install. Check out your gem.